# What are the steps to parametrize a curve and solve its integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, parametrization

> Let C be the piece of the curve of intersection of the cylinder $y = x^2$
> and the plane
> $x + y + z = 0$ between the points $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(2, 4, −6)$.
>
> Parametrize C and compute $$\int _C\sqrt{2+4x+8y}\:ds$$

How would I do this?

Here's what I tried:

Let $x=t$

So then: $y=t^2$

Then I use a random vector function $r(t) = (t,t^2)$

So:

$r(0) = (0,0)$ and $r(2) = (2,4)$

And those equal my points. But how do I get the Z value? Do I just throw in another value like:

$r(t) = (t,t^2,-t^2-2)$

How does it work? I have no clue how to solve this. I'm guessing my bounds are $0->2$ when I differentiate in respect to dt.

So then:

$$ds = ||r'(t)|| = ||(1,2t,-2t)|| = \sqrt{1+8t^2}$$

Therefore my integral is:

$$\int _0^2\:\left(t^2\right)\left(\sqrt{1+8t^2}\right)dt$$

Is this right?

But like. Even if it IS right, how do I get the parametrization without guessing and checking? I feel like I just used random logic to get to my integral instead of actual steps. So essentially I'm wondering, how to parametrize the curve of intersection.

Like what if it wasn't just $x=t$? Do you just eyeball the parametrization?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us find a parametrisation $r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ such that $r(0)=(0,0,0)$ and $r(1)=(2,4,-6)$. We also require that $$x(t)+y(t)+z(t)=0\quad\text{and}\quad y(t)=x(t)^2\quad\forall\ t\in[0,1].$$ If we set $x(t)=2t$, then the two equations above demand that $$y(t)=x(t)^2=4t^2\quad\text{and}\quad z(t)=-(x(t)+y(t))=-2t-4t^2.$$ So we get the parametrisation
$$r(t)=(2t,4t^2,-2t-4t^2).$$
As for "how do I get the parmetrisation without guessing and checking" - well, there is a level of choice. I chose the limits of $t$, then I chose an $x(t)$ that works. From there $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are determined by those choices.

I should add that you should check that $r'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Otherwise this would correspond to the curve having a 'cusp'.

Comment: wait so why is the middle one negative, and couldn't you just divide all of them by 2? does that mean you just "set" like randomly picked a x(t)=2t? Like, howd you determine that r(0) had to be (0,0,0) instead of like r(4) = (0,0,0) do you just set those before hand? sorry i just really can't understand this. I'm scared of setting things before hand

Comment: Sorry that middle one was a typo. Yes, you can choose any limits for $t$ you like, but from $0$ to $1$ is nice. Then as long as your parametrisation satisfies the mentioned conditions then it IS the curve you are interested in. I will add another parametrisation if that helps your understanding.

Comment: thank you, may I suggest this one: $xe^y$ where c is the curve from $(3,0)$ to $(7,8)$  how to parametize this one

Comment: What do you mean $xe^y$. This is just an expression, it does not describe a curve. You would have to say $xe^y=1$ (or something) and then say what the limits are,  i.e. $x\in[3,7]$.

Comment: that's what my problem asks me to do, see my updated post for the picture

Comment: $xe^y$ is the function you are integrating, The curve you are integrating over is a straight line - which is what they mean by "line segment".

Comment: oh ok. so how would i parametize that. I tried following your steps but i can't seem to make it work

Comment: It is a straight line. Figure out the equation of the straight line (you have two points), then set the limits of $t$ (anything you want), set $x(t)$ (anything such that it satisfies the correct limits), and the $y(t)$ will be determined by the equation of the line.

Comment: ooooh ok! thanks so much i got it now